# Binary splitting an array and retrieving "leaf" arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a number of entries in an array (`FT = [-10.5, 6.5, 7.5, -7.5]`) which I am applying on binary splitting to append to a result array of arrays (`LT = [[-10.5],[6.5, 7.5, -7.5],[6.5,7.5],[-7.5]`] the tree describing the splitting for my example is below:

```
[-10.5, 6.5, 7.5, -7.5]
                /         \
          [-10.5]        [6.5, 7.5, -7.5]
                            /      \
                    [6.5, 7.5]       [ -7.5]
```

Now from the array `LT` I want to retrieve only "leaf" arrays (`T = [[-10.5],[6.5,7.5],[-7.5]]`) given the size of the initial array `FT`.
How to achieve this (get `T`) in Java?

Comment: If `LT` is `[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2], [1], [2]]`, how would I know whether the original split was into [1, 2, 1], [1, 2] and the subsequent split split the latter array, or the original split was into [1, 2, 1], [2], the former array then being further split?

Comment: @Ole VV the splitting is done of course (since theres  the FT array already)

Comment: Am I allowed to ask whether this is homework or an exercise? In other words: Is it better that we point or guide you in the right direction and leave as much as possible to yourself? Or is it better when we solve your problem as fully as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am presenting a way of thinking about your problem. I am not fledgling it out into a full algorithm; I am leaving some parts for yourself to fill in.

First, if `LT` is empty, no splitting has occurred. In this case the original `FT` was the leaf array, and we have no way of telling what it was. The problem cannot be solved.

If `LT` contains `n` arrays, then there must exist some `m` (0 < `m` < `n`) so that the first `m` arrays form the left subtree and the rest form the right subtree. We don’t know `m`, so we simply try all possible values of `m` in turn. For each possible `m` we check whether a solution for this value of `m` is possible by trying to reconstruct each subtree.

So define an auxiliary method to check if a part of `LT` can form a subtree and return the leaves if it can.

Your auxiliary method will work like this: If there is only one array, it’s a leaf, so return it. If there are two arrays, they cannot form a subtree. I there are three, they form a subtree exactly if the first is the concatenation of the other two. If there are more than three, then again we need to consider all the possibilities of how they are distributed into subtrees. The difference from before is that we know which full array the subtrees come from, namely the frontmost array. So all solutions should be checked against this. For starters, if the second array is not a prefix of the first, we cannot have a subtree.

Your algorithm will no doubt get recursive at some point.

Pruning opportunity: It seems to me that a binary tree always has an odd number of leaves. So for a solution to exist `n` needs to be even and `m` needs to be odd.

I would consider coding my algorithm using lists rather than arrays because I think it’s more convenient to pass lists of lists rather than arrays of arrays or lists of arrays around.

Happy further refinement and coding.

Comment: forget about it, now if you know the initial size of the array to split doesn't that give you an indication about the elements generated by a binary split and therefore an indication on the number of leaves ?